# Need help toggling this button when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

After the visibility of the selected element is changed to "visible" on the click of the button, I would like it to change back to "hidden" when the button is clicked again. So basically I would like to toggle the button.

But it seems not to be working. Can I get some direction as to what to do to solve this?

```
//Imported jumbotron element

var jumbo = document.getElementById("bill-board");

//project, skills and contact elements

var projects = document.getElementById("projects");
var skills = document.getElementById("skills");
var contact = document.getElementById("contact");


//Functionality that takes place when projects, skills and contact are clicked

//When the projects element is clicked

projects.addEventListener("click", () => {


    if(document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden") {
        one.style.visibility = "visible";
        jumbo.textContent = "Projects";
        console.log("It's visible and bill-board is changed to projects");
    } else {
        one.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

})


//When skills element is clicked

skills.addEventListener("click", () => {

    if(document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "hidden") {
        two.style.visibility = "visible";
        jumbo.textContent = "skills";
        console.log("It's visible and bill-board is changed to skills");
    } else {
        one.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

})


//When contact element is clicked

contact.addEventListener("click", () => {

    if(document.getElementById("three").style.visibility = "hidden") {
        three.style.visibility = "visible";
        jumbo.textContent = "Contacts";
        console.log("It's visible and bill-board is changed to contacts");
    } else {
        one.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

## Hi

### Basically there are two problems

#### Problem 1

you are checking the status of visibility incorrectly.

```
if(document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden")
```

This should be as follows:

```
if(document.getElementById("one").style.visibility == "hidden")
```

The equality operator is `==`.

#### Problem 2

inside this snippet

```
if(document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden") {
    one.style.visibility = "visible";
    jumbo.textContent = "Projects";
    console.log("It's visible and bill-board is changed to projects");
} else {
    one.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

you are not storing the element you got by calling

```
document.getElementById("one")
```

into the variable "one" ..i.e the above snippet should be this.

```
let one = document.getElementById("one");
if(one.style.visibility == "hidden") {
    one.style.visibility = "visible";
    jumbo.textContent = "Projects";
    console.log("It's visible and bill-board is changed to projects");
} else {
    one.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Similarly you should do for two and three.